Using isomorphism between field extensions to calculate roots inexactly
Given a polynomial $P(x)\in K[x]$ and a field isomorphism $\phi:K\xrightarrow{} K'$. We can define the conjugate polynomial $P'(x) = \sum \phi(p_i)x^i$. Given the roots of $P(x)$, we can calculate the roots of $P'(x)$, because we know that $\phi$ extends to an isomorphism $\psi$ between the splitting fields.
I was wondering if it is possible to determine $\psi$ without exactly calculating the roots of $P(x)$. For example if we have a numerical approximation of the roots can we consistently map these close to roots of $P'(x)$?
If you would have exact solutions you can determine the splitting field explicitly and find an isomorphism $\psi$ that extends $\phi$. But without an exact form of the roots I find it difficult to think about this isomorphism.

I'm not at all sure what the ramifications of the below observation are to your question. Hence a comment only. As $1+\sqrt2$ and $1-\sqrt2$ are the roots of the quadratic $x^2-2x-1$, it follows that $(1+\sqrt2)^{100}\approx1.89482\cdot10^{38}$ and
$(1-\sqrt2)^{100}\approx5.27754\cdot10^{-39}$ share the same (quadratic) minimal polynomial. I think that using suitable Pisot numbers you can find cubics with two zeros very close to zero, and a third huge root.

For example if $\alpha$ ranges over the roots of $x^3-x^2-1$, then $\alpha^{100}$ ranges over the roots of some other cubic (irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$), so the possibilities for $\alpha^{100}$ are approximately $-4.79316\cdot10^{-9}\pm i 1.45066\cdot10^{-9}$ and $3.98643\cdot10^{16}$. So you need relatively high precision to distinguish those two small roots. And by going to higher powers we can make them both arbitrarily close to zero (and hence also each other).
